# Add Requirements to Default [Authorize] policy

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

In ASP.Net Core there are custom policies that you can add to `.AddAuthorization`.

However, I need to add a requirement to the default policy because it will be used in every request. Is there a way I can do this without having to create a custom policy and always specifying it with `[Authorize("Policy")]`?

```
services.AddAuthorization(options =>
            {
                options.AddPolicy("Unexpired",
                    policy => policy.Requirements.Add(new <requirement>));
            ...
```

Is there a way to make this policy part of the default?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In ASP.NET Core 5, it's probably the `option`'s `DefaultPolicy` you're looking for:

```cs
var unexpiredPolicy = new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder()
    .RequireAuthenticatedUser() // Remove if you don't need the user to be authenticated
    .AddRequirements(new MyRequirement())
    .Build();
services.AddSingleton<IAuthorizationHandler, MyRequirementHandler>();

services.AddAuthorization(options =>
{
    // This line can be omitted if you don't need to be
    // able to explicitly set the policy
    options.AddPolicy("Unexpired", unexpiredPolicy);

    // If no policy specified, use this
    options.DefaultPolicy = unexpiredPolicy;
});
```

Comment: Works great, but the old "Unexpired" policy isn't necessary anymore and doesn't need to be created. Thanks!